# Why i cant install "express"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, terminal, npm

first i installed :

```
lds-MacBook-Pro:~ ldnwty$ node --version
v0.10.31
lds-MacBook-Pro:~ ldnwty$ npm --version
1.4.23
lds-MacBook-Pro:~ ldnwty$ express --version
4.8.0
```

then when i want to install the express in my project :

```
lds-MacBook-Pro:contacts ldnwty$ npm install express
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No repository field.
express@4.9.6 ../../node_modules/express
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── cookie-signature@1.0.5
├── finalhandler@0.2.0
├── media-typer@0.3.0
├── vary@1.0.0
├── methods@1.1.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── serve-static@1.6.4
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.3
├── depd@0.4.5
├── qs@2.2.4
├── on-finished@2.1.0 (ee-first@1.0.5)
├── etag@1.4.0 (crc@3.0.0)
├── debug@2.0.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.3 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@0.1.3)
├── send@0.9.3 (destroy@1.0.3, mime@1.2.11, ms@0.6.2)
├── type-is@1.5.2 (mime-types@2.0.2)
└── accepts@1.1.1 (negotiator@0.4.8, mime-types@2.0.2)
```

and its not installing it also with "sudo".

what can i do?

Comment: What makes you think that it hasn't been installed?

Comment: its not showed at my local folder of my project when i do ls , theres no "node_modules" -> express

Answer (score 0):

It's already installed (could be globally, so it isn't in your app's `node_modules` directory), you should be able to include it in your code as follow:

```
var express = require('express');
```

If you'd like to update it (since there seems to be a new version), run:

```
npm update
```

Comment: But why i cant see this folder in my app folder? when i install it local in my app folder i need to see the "node_nodule" folder , no ?

Comment: It could be installed globally. Then it's located elsewhere and accessible by all your Node apps.  You should be able to do this by adding `-g` to your `npm install` command.